# Other Alphabet [Turkish Language] sorting in Index

Tags: indexing, sorting, imakeidx, alphabet

My code;

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.mst}
heading_prefix "{\\bfseries\\hfil "
heading_suffix "\\hfil}\\nopagebreak\n"
headings_flag 1
symhead_positive "Semboller"
numhead_positive "Numaralar"
delim_0 "\\dotfill"
delim_1 "\\dotfill"
delim_2 "\\dotfill"
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\index{Apple}\index{Blackberry}\index{Current}\index{Çay}\index{çay}
\index{Date}\index{Eggplant}\index{Fake}\index{Grape}\index{History}
\index{Ilımlı}\index{İzmir}\index{ideal}\index{Jackfruit}
\index{Kitchen}\index{Lemon}\index{Mango}\index{Narrow}
\index{Over}\index{Özgür}\index{özel}\index{Pear}\index{Raspberry}
\index{Satsuma}\index{Şimşek}\index{şimşek}\index{Tomato}
\index{Upgrade}\index{Ülke}\index{ülke}\index{View}
\index{Yes}\index{Zebra}\index{70}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

The Turkish Alphabet is;

A B C Ç D E F G Ğ H I İ J K L M N O Ö P R S Ş T U Ü V Y Z

a b c ç d e f g ğ ı i j k l m n o ö p r s ş t u ü v y z.

I am not able to sort in Turkish Alphabet in Index.

I find another same question, but don't working. Does anyone know how to fix it in LaTeX?

Note:`İ` is uppercase of `i` and `ı` is lowercase of `I` in my language.

**If it is possible to make it without using any babel and/or xindy packages it will really helpful to me. I mean that I wanna do it via adding some codes to my code that stated above.**

Comment: I think you have to use Xindy and not MakeIndex.

Comment: @egreg: I check it.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `\documentclass[turkish...]{...}\usepackage{babel}`?

Comment: @egreg `texindy` improves the sort (if that's the right way to do it), but some characters are still sorted to the start of the index with numbers: İ, Ş, ş. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My (incomplete) solution with your helps

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[noautomatic,nonewpage]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=3]
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.mst}
heading_prefix "{\\bfseries\\hfil "
heading_suffix "\\hfil}\\nopagebreak\n"
headings_flag 1
symhead_positive "Semboller"
numhead_positive "Numaralar"
delim_0 "\\dotfill"
delim_1 "\\dotfill"
delim_2 "\\dotfill"
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\index{Apple} A \index{Blackberry}\index{Current}\index{Çay}\index{çay}
\index{Date}\index{Eggplant}\index{Fake}\index{Grape}\index{History}
\index{Ilımlı}\index{İzmir}\index{ideal}\index{Jackfruit}
\index{Kitchen}\index{Lemon}\index{Mango}\index{Narrow}
\index{Over}\index{Özgür}\index{özel}\index{Pear}\index{Raspberry}
\index{Satsuma}\index{Şimşek}\index{şimşek}\index{Tomato}
\index{Upgrade}\index{Ülke}\index{ülke}\index{View}
\index{Yes}\index{Zebra}\index{70}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Then

1) (If not installed)

> sudo apt-get install xindy

2) First, LaTeX to PDF

[image]

3)

> texindy -L turkish -M lang/turkish/utf8 sample.idx

4) Last, LaTeX to PDF

[image]

Why incomplete? Because `\dotfill`, `symhead_positive`, and `numhead_positive` are disappearing. Again with your help I understood that the solution is hidden in it.

> begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xdy}
>
> ...
>
> \end{filecontents*}

Next Question : [Lost \dotfill After The texindy command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/270182/33075)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `xindy` for sorting non-western languages. Try to run this command:

```
xindy -M texindy -L turkish -C utf8 sample.idx
```

[image]

I am not sure whether the sorting is correct, at least sorting of `i` and `İ` looks suspiciuos to me

Comment: Almost there but still not correct, ö and Ö should be under separate letter. And as you noticed lower and upper case i,ü,ç and ş is wrong too. But at least they show up at the correct locations.

Comment: @percusse perhaps this should be reported to xindy bug tracker by someone with knowledge of correct Turkish sorting

Comment: The (Iıİi)'s don't really have a solution, if your index is bilingual. If, for example, you sort under the Turkish rules, then the index entries for 'Ideal' and 'ideal' will be classified under two separate initial letters, which is confusing, independently of whether it is 'correct' or not. General indices, IMHO, should be all lowercase except for proper nouns (which perhaps should be in a separate index). But then again, that might not suit those who speak German.