# Lost \dotfill After The texindy command

Tags: indexing, languages, sorting, alphabet

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}

\makeindex
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.mst}
heading_prefix "{\\bfseries\\hfil "
heading_suffix "\\hfil}\\nopagebreak\n"
headings_flag 1
delim_0 "\\dotfill"
delim_1 "\\dotfill"
delim_2 "\\dotfill"
\end{filecontents} 

\begin{document}

a
\index{Özgür}
\newpage

b
\index{Şemsiye}
\newpage

c
\index{Çatal}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

And output,

[image]

And `texindy -L turkish -M lang/turkish/utf8 filename.idx` in terminal/console,

and output

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix it?

**Herbert's answer**

[image]

Comment: Xindy doesn't read `\jobname.mst`.

Comment: @egreg, for example, I did wrote **jobname.idx**. As a matter of fact, the MWE file name is **sort.tex** I changed my answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. Your document creates `sort.mst` and MakeIndex will see it and load it for making the index. But Xindy never looks at that file, which is specific for MakeIndex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define a xindx style file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\makeindex

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xdy}
(markup-locclass-list :open ", \dotfill{}")
\end{filecontents*} 

\begin{document}

a
\index{Özgür}
\newpage

b
\index{Şemsiye}
\newpage

c
\index{Çatal}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

run

```
pdflatex <file>
texindy -C utf8 -L turkish -M <file>.xdy <file>.idx
pdflatex <file>
```

[image]

Comment: almost working. Maybe, lang turkish missing in texindy commands. I don't add it. I added but not worked. Please see edited my answer. Herbert

Comment: see my edited answer for the `texindy` call. You have to define the language

Comment: sorting is true but **punctuation** is wrong. Also **,** missing. Please see edited my question.

Comment: Insert the comma before `\dotfill`: `(markup-locclass-list :open ", \dotfill{}")` And, of course, use the `-L turkish` key to get the correct letters